# ServletContext in Spring Application

Tags: spring, servlets

I have one simple question.

If web.xml web application descriptor like this.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
        /WEB-INF/anotherContext.xml,
        /WEB-INF/another2Context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

ContextLoaderListener create three differents ServletContexts or three differents ServletContext childs inside one general parent ServletContext?

dispatcher-servlet.xml configuration of DispatcherServlet is another child than others three contexts above?

**SOLUTION**

I have been investigating about this area, I have created one example application, and every xml files from  make one ServletContext only, the same root ServletContext application created by ContextLoaderListener.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can take a look at this old answer, have a great explanation.

[Namespace vs contextConfigLocation Spring init parameters in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818047/namespace-vs-contextconfiglocation-spring-init-parameters-in-web-xml)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think that extensive explanation not resolve my dude. I want to know if more than one xml file in <context-param> make one root servletcontext or one root servletcontext by each file.